# Select Objects By Crossing Window

Tags: c#, select, entity, autocad

I am trying to select more entities with by command "Editor.SelectCrossingWindow" but selection status gives "error" even if I use example code in AutoDesk Network

```
PromptSelectionResult acSSPrompt;
acSSPrompt = acDocEd.SelectCrossingWindow(new Point3d(2, 2, 0),
                                            new Point3d(10, 8, 0));


if (acSSPrompt.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
{
    SelectionSet acSSet = acSSPrompt.Value;

    Application.ShowAlertDialog("Number of objects selected: " +
                                acSSet.Count.ToString());
}
```

If I use ed.SelectAll then the code works

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

SelectCrossingWindow (as all selections using hard coded points input) cannot select entities which are not visible in the current viewport. So, to insure a selection works, you have to make zoom extents before doing the selection. The simples way to make a Zoom Extents is using the COM API with the dynamic type to avoid referencing Interop libraries.

```
        dynamic acadApp = Application.AcadApplication;
        acadApp.ZoomExtents();

        var selectionResult = ed.SelectCrossingWindow(
            new Point3d(2, 2, 0), new Point3d(10, 8, 0));

        acadApp.ZoomPrevious();

        if (selectionResult.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
        {
            Application.ShowAlertDialog(
                "Number of objects selected: " + selectionResult.Value.Count);
        }
```